# get The Value selected from custom-select to javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have custom-select in td table so i need when click on button update get what the selected item to JavaScript. How can i do this?

```
    @foreach ($bookinghalls as $item)
          <td>{{$item->id}}</td>
    <td>{{$item->name}}</td>
   <td >{{$item->hall_name}}</td>
    <td>{{$item->from_date}}</td>
    <td>{{$item->to_date}}</td>
    <td>{{$item->type_booking}}</td>  
            <td id ="intervel"><select class="custom-select mr-sm-2" name="intervel" >
        @if ($item->pay==0)
        <option value="0">not pay </option>    
        <option value="1">pay </option>

        @else ($item->pay==1)
        <option value="1">pay </option>
        <option value="0">not pay </option>
        @endif
        </td>
         <td><button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary but_update"  name="imagaid"   >update</button>   </td>
```

And this JavaScript:

```
var table_hallbooking = $("#table_bookinghall").DataTable();
table_hallbooking.on("click", ".but_update", function() {
  $tr = $(this).closest("tr");
  var data = $tr
    .children("td")
    .map(function() {
      return $(this).text();
    })
    .get();
  $("#pay").val(data[6]);
  var pay = $("#intervel").val();
  console.log(pay);
});
```

The problem when the update button is clicked, it gives me all the values in  custom-select but I need what the user selected.

Comment: `#intervel` is the TD, not the select, so `$("#intervel").val();` doesn't get the right value. Try assigning an ID to the select.

Comment: ok … I add  the id to the <select> but when click on the button  the console display null and  custom-select on the table showing empty  why ???

Comment: Please update your question, so we can see what you did and try to help.

Comment: I've noticed that you're creating multiple selects, because you're doing this inside a loop, so, you need to assign unique id to each element, otherwise it will be really hard to get it working right.

Answer (score 0):

`$('#intervel')` is the selector for `<td>` tag. Set an id attribute to your `<select>` tag and then use it to get the value.

Comment: I do it but in the click select showing empty and print on the console null..what's a problem  ??